# Are virtual winglets a viable concept?

Tags: aircraft-design, aerodynamics, winglets

Just read [this abstract](https://abstracts.societyforscience.org/Home/PrintPdf/15282) by a Regeneron STS finalist.  Is the idea of a virtual winglet a viable concept? Seems interesting.

Comment: Somebody needs to tell West Virginia University to start teaching kids proper English. The word "virtual" does not mean what they think it means. I mean, W. Virginia has a ton of issues with education, SAT's and IQ's, but this is over the top. All they are thinking of is redirection of airflow to provide the same effect on the wing as a winglet would.

Comment: Oh, come on. It says "high school" in the title, you can't judge it by the same standards as a college paper.

Comment: From Webster: "being such in essence or effect though not formally recognized or admitted".  Doing the job of a winglet although not actually being one physically.  I'd say that could be construed to fit.

Comment: @JohnK Not even closed. Second part of that sentence kills your argument. :)

Comment: @JuanJimenez explain.

Comment: The effect of a winglet is quite recognized and admitted. What the paper proposes is quite real and measurable. Nothing virtual about it. The thing about virtual is that it doesn't exist.

Comment: You are applying a definition that only applies in the computer world. There are others.  In the physical world, virtual doesn't mean it doesn't exist.  The virtual refers to the fact that even though the effect is there, the physical object, or concept, nominally associated with that effect is of a radically different form.  Like this device.  It's not a physical winglet, but has the same effect as a winglet (in theory).  It's virtually a winglet.  Thay guy over there is a virtual dictator.  He exists; he is not officially a dictator, but he exercises powers that have the same result.

Answer (score 2):

Aston Martin do something similar with their '[Aeroblade](https://www.motorauthority.com/news/1105032_aston-martin-clears-the-air-on-new-db11s-aeroblade)', which replaces the rear spoiler, so the concept of using air to guide surrounding air is viable. Whether it's more efficient than using a physical object, remains to be seen.